# Should we build our native SDK using Swift or Objective-C and are there any SDK's out there entirely built on Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

My company is currently planning on providing our services and UI components in the form of native SDK. What are pros and cons of building the SDK in Swift vs Objective-C?

Note: Our clients who will be integrating our SDK will be either using Swift or Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly encourage watching this talk by [Jonathan Blocksom](https://twitter.com/jblocksom): http://realm.io/news/swift-objc-best-friends-forever/

It says:

"Swift and Objective-C work together fairly well, so there are many reasons why you would want to include both in a single project. There may be a handy Swift library that you want to use in Objective-C, or vice versa. If you have a big Obj-C codebase and you want to learn Swift, now would be a good time to do that as well. Swift was built for Objective-C compatibility and also works with C, but not with C++. Many types in Objective-C translate over to Swift fairly well: BOOL to Bool, NSInteger to Int, SEL to Selector, and so on."

In my limited experience, using Objective-C code from Swift is a more common use-case and fairly trivial. Using Swift code from Objective-C is certainly possible, but it has some gotchas: Specifically, check "Alamofire in Obj-C Case Study" in the video.

Alamofire is an HTTP networking library written in Swift, from the [creator](https://github.com/mattt) of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking): https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Also, I would encourage you to read the official document: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/using-swift-cocoa-objective/id888894773?mt=11

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resources, it is helpful. If we develop our SDK using swift and our client uses Objective-C as their base language, would it make it difficult for them to integrate?

Comment: In my opinion, it's easier to use Objective-C code from Swift than the other way around. Again, it really depends on your use-case and I would encourage you to check the "Alamofire in Obj-C Case Study" section in the video.